# Need to change letters to other letters (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a school mini project, and we basically need to change letters that have been inputted into another letter (which is selected from a premade list), making a code machine like program. I have searched the web and stackoverflow, and cant find anything on it, and dont really know where to start.

What I want the programme to sort of do is this, say I input the word "hello". The program will change the word to "loaaw" for example, with L being H, A being E, A being L and W being O. These translations will be set before hand, in a big list, basically selecting which letter is sent back when a letter is sent in.

Comment: You should try first, and ask here if you get problems.

Comment: You can start here -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: "dont really know where to start." -> I would suggest starting by doing a few Python tutorials, there are plenty online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
orig = 'hello'
# table = {'h': 'L', 'e': 'O', 'l': 'A', 'o': 'W' }
# table_tr = dict( (ord(a), ord(b))  for a,b in table.items() ) 
table_tr = str.maketrans('helo', 'LOAW')
res = orig.translate(table_tr)
print(res)
```

(this is for python3; for python2 you need to `import string` and use `string.maketrans`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not tried anything. I can give you a direction. In Python there are two methods associated with string. They are *maketrans(arg1, arg2)* and *translate(table)*.

*maketrans* creates table of translation for you

*translate* translates text with the help of table created by maketrans

Please try and ask questions if you get struck.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down the task into steps then work out how to do each.

For example in its most basic form:

- take in an input
- do something to that text
- give the output

I would start by doing the easiest parts - take in the input and then output it again - and then break down the central part into smaller pieces again and work on these one at a time.